# PHP long string pattern replacement with array

Tags: php, regex

Lets say I have string

```
$pattern = "Hello my name is %name%. I'am %age% years old and I live in %city%."
```

And an indexed array to replace this string

```
$replacementArray = array("name"=>"Peter", "age"=>"15", "city"=>"Stockholm");
```

> *Pleace notice named array keys are same with my pattern keys)*
>
> *"**name**"=>"Peter", my name is **%name%***

What is the most efficient way of doing this an how can I do it.

I am not sure but I think it needs some regex replacements. I am very new to PHP.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Sure. I tried to do it with vsprintf(), Hello my name is %s. But vsprintf doesn't work with arrays I think...

Comment: ^ Include this in your question! And show your work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just loop through all replacements which I then replace with `str_replace()` in your pattern)

```
<?php

    $pattern = "Hello my name is %name%. I'am %age% years old and I live in %city%.";
    $replacementArray = ["name" => "Peter", "age" => "15", "city" => "Stockholm"];

    foreach($replacementArray as $k => $v) {
        $pattern = str_replace("%$k%", $v, $pattern);
    }

    echo $pattern;

?>
```

output:

```
Hello my name is Peter. I'am 15 years old and I live in Stockholm.
```

---

You can also do it the other way around and just append a `%` before and after each key like this:

```
echo str_replace(array_map(function($v){return "%$v%";}, array_keys($replacementArray)), array_values($replacementArray), $pattern);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made some benchmark tests with both methods and i see that the foreach method works almost 4 times faster. So i will use foreach because sometimes $pattern string can be so much longer. `Results : array_map -> 2.234s, foreach  -> 0.583s`  `(Test : strlen($pattern) =426, sizeof($replacementArray)=14, loops: 20.000)`

Answer (score 0):

This expression will get the pattern keys from your string,

```
preg_match_all('/\%(.*?)\%/',$pattern, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex or try this

loop over $replacement array

```
 foreach($replacement as $key=>$val){
   $pattern = str_replace($key,$val,$pattern);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your own code? (UPDATE: Have you looked at the output?)