# Best practice to replace a string with html code (results from array)

Tags: php

Given a string like this...

```
$htmlPattern = "User name is: #name# and user company is #company#";
```

How do I replace the substrings `#name#` and `#company#` with elements from variables?

For example if `$name` is `"John"` and `$company` is `Microsoft`, how can I produce the string `User name is: John and user company is: Microsoft`?

Comment: Str_replace function in php is probably the best bet. https://theprogrammingexpert.com/php-str-replace/

Comment: The answer to a very similar question should get you close to your goal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29512110/4342563

Comment: Can you please show more code, what does your array look like? Do you need to pull OUT #name# and #company# from $htmlPattern = "User name is: #name# and user company is #company#";?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the array so that the keys include `#` around them. Then you can use this as the replacement argument with [`strtr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

```
$myArr = [
    ["#name#" => "John", "#company#" => "Microsoft"],
    ["#name#" => "Erica", "#company#" => "Apple"]
];

foreach ($myArr as $row) {
    $emptyHtml  .= strtr($htmlPattern, $row)
}
```

Comment: The issue is: I need to get "name" and "company" dinamically! (get what is inside #...#). Because I can recieve different values.

Comment: i.e: If html pattern $row['ANYTHING'] where anything is the thing extracted from between #...#

Comment: Could you change the keys in `$myArr` to include the `#`? I've updated the answer to show how you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple str_replace inside each other like this:

```
<?php

$name = "jhon";
$company = "microsoft";

$htmlPattern = "<div>User name is: #name# and user company is #company#</div>";
 
$res = str_replace("#name#",$name,str_replace("#company#",$company,$htmlPattern));

print($res);


?>
```